# How to update node data in a D3.js force graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking for a way to update multiple node attributes and appended elements on data change.

Here is how I'm trying to do it right now.
This function gets called every-time node or link data changes.

```
function restart() {

  link = link.data(links);

  link
    .enter().insert("line", ".node")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .on('click' , function(d, i){ 
      console.log(d);
      links.splice(i,1);
      restart();
    })
    .on("mouseover", function() { 
      d3.select(this).style("stroke","red"); 
      d3.select(this).style("stroke-width","5px"); 
    })
    .on("mouseout", function() { 
      d3.select(this).style("stroke","#999");
      d3.select(this).style("stroke-width","initial");  
    });

  link
    .exit().remove();

  node = node.data(nodes);

  node
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(node_drag);

  node
    .insert("circle", ".cursor")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return calcSize(d.links+1); })

  node
    .append("text")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.links });

  node
    .exit().remove();

  force.start();

}
```

The full code at the current state can be seen here: http://jsbin.com/takatugazo/edit?html,js,output

The expected behaviour is that when two nodes get dragged into each other they create a link and the more links they have the bigger they get.

Comment: I see your code is working as expected, what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It is not, the appended text is the most clear proof it's not, it should update when d.links changes. The size of the nodes is also not updating as I want, but I believe that figuring out how to update the text will show me how to fix that also

Answer (score 0):

Your appended text IS updating. The only issue seems to be that the instead of replacing the old text, it's adding a `<text>` element on top. If you just inspect a node, you'll find multiple `<text>` elements based on how many links it has. For some reason your code doesn't update the text the way it should.

Try removing the text element before you append one:

```
node.select("text").remove()

node
.append("text")
.attr("dx", 12)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return d.links });

node
.exit().remove();
```

I made those changes in JS Bin and it seems to work for me (with a bit of a delay): http://jsbin.com/goqumutelu/edit?html,js,output

There is a delay in the dragend() function whenever is a link is pushed (not sure if intentional?) So if you don't want the delay: removing the timeout, or simply replacing the delay value (1500) to 0 should solve that: http://jsbin.com/hazecozumu/1/edit?html,js,output

About the size of the nodes, what's wrong it? How else did you want it to update?